# Why only hyperplanes in support-vector machines?

Tags: data-mining, svm, unsupervised-learning

I only recently learnt about support vector machines. From what I understood, hyperplanes are used to separate the data (raised to the higher dimension) into two mutually exclusive parts (partitions). My question is why should it be a hyperplane and not a surface with a curvature(s)? Wouldn't that provide a better suited separating 'surface'?

Comment: To my limited layman understanding, the space itself is manipulated to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nonlinear classification is possible.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Nonlinear_classification

Answer (score 2):

There exists something called a Kernel Function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick

From what I remember from a Data Mining class, you perform a non-linear transformation of each point into a higher dimension. Say your data is in just two dimensions and is not linearly separable. If you convert each `(x, y)` into `(x, y, z)` (or more dimensions if necessary, probably likely) using a Kernel Function then you may be able to separate the data with a plane / hyperplane / higher dimensional hyperplane without involving curvature.

As an example of a Kernel Function, apply this to "generate" a higher dimension, math is similar to binomial expansion: `f(x, y) == (x*x, y*y, 2xy)`

Answer (score 2):

That the hyperplane does not *really* exist. It is not *computed*. It is not really treated as a hyperplane either.

The SVM decision is based on the similarity to the support vectors; which *implicitly* defines a hyperplane in some Euclidean space. When using a kernel function, this does *not* need to be your original data space; and it may well be non-linear in the original data space, if you are using a non-linear kernel function for computing your similarities.